# Pivot Chart - 3 date columns, how to show counts of the dates by month?

Tags: excel, date, pivot-table, powerquery, pivot-chart

My goal is to have a count of three different dates by month in a bar chart. Currently we are using a count if formula then building the chart above that, would like a cleaner solution. I have three columns, Open, Action, and closed dates. Adding all three to the axis doesn't produce the right results. I'm stuck. Is there something in the pivot that I can change? I'm pulling the data in via Power Query, is there something there I can change? Many thanks :-)
[Ideal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbyLh.png)

[image]

**Recent Action and Closed dates are not show up, that seems to be the real issue. Why and how to fix it?**

[image]
[image]

Sample of data
[image]

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "count three different dates"? Please give an example. 2) If "adding all three is not right", how do u want to calculate it?.  Better give some sample data. Thanks.

Comment: Good call outs Oliver. I've included a small sample of the data. Goal is count of date per month. I can get the counts in the values box, but when I add it to the Axis it breaks. I can have one of the dates in the axis, but if you add a 2nd BOOM it breaks.

Comment: Zack, I can't comprehend your info: 1) In your ideal state, data points of the purple line is not the sum of the 3 bars ("sum of dates"), how can you actually calculate these points?, 2) In the pivot table, there's an "Issue date" field, which group the dates of Open/Action/Close. So, unless there're some rows within the 3 cols of dates, the count of the three "dates" should be the same (but isn't the case in your sample, that puzzles me).   So, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve  ( I thought you want to group all the Open/Action/Close dates by month and add a "Total" line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a date table in Power Query.
Also in Power query, duped my data then deleted all but the columns I didn't need.
Unpivoted the three date columns.
Joined the new date to the date table.
Graphs fine.